# Visual Studio Code Edit From External GUI

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create a designer for the code of the current active editor (a tab in VSCode). So I would like to ask you, how this is accomplishable.

In this video the developer is showing impressively that this is possible:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgPYdtcNRwg

I looked already for the some API's like https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors, but they all doesn't offer what I want: grab and manipulate existing code of current tab, or maybe I am missing something?

Perhaps I have to think out of the box and work with the file path of current tab/editor, and change the code in files on the filesystem directly?

I am grateful for any hint and help.

Comment: the form designer is not written in VSC but is an external program that is launched by the PowerShell extension, this program modifies the files on disk and also uses the latest version of the file before making changes, so you can edit the file in VSC

Comment: Ah okay, just like I thought. Thanks for advice.